# Why does Java allow the explicit conversion of expressions of type Object to A<B<C>>, of type A<?> to A<B<C>> but not of type A<B<?>> to A<B<C>>?

Tags: java, generics, casting

Java will let me do this:

```
public static class SomeType<I>{}

private static Map<Class<?>, Object> m = new HashMap<Class<?>, Object>();

public static <X> List<SomeType<X>> getList(Class<X> clazz)
{
     return (List<SomeType<X>>)m.get(clazz);//warning
}
```

It will also let me do this:

```
public static class SomeType<I>{}

private static Map<Class<?>, List<?>> m = new HashMap<Class<?>, List<?>>();

public static <X> List<SomeType<X>> getList(Class<X> clazz)
{
    return (List<SomeType<X>>)m.get(clazz);//warning
}
```

But it won't let me do this:

```
public static class SomeType<I>{}

private static Map<Class<?>, List<SomeType<?>>> m = new HashMap<Class<?>, List<SomeType<?>>>();

public static <X> List<SomeType<X>> getList(Class<X> clazz)
{
    return (List<SomeType<X>>)m.get(clazz);//will not compile
}
```

unless I resort to the following workaround:

```
public static class SomeType<I>{}

private static Map<Class<?>, List<SomeType<?>>> m = new HashMap<Class<?>, List<SomeType<?>>>();

public static <X> List<SomeType<X>> getList(Class<X> clazz)
{
    return (List<SomeType<X>>)(Object)m.get(clazz);//warning
}
```

So java makes it possible to explicitly convert from to Object to `A<B<C>>`, from `A<?>` to `A<B<C>>` but not from `A<B<?>>` to `A<B<C>>`.

why is that?

Comment: related: [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Comment: @JSmith Please don't just delete your questions after you got an answer for it. Accept the answer instead or at least explain why you want to delete the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Java will not compile type casts that provably cannot succeed** (assuming the things are the type they are declared as, and assuming that the value is not `null`). For a type cast to be possible to succeed, it must be (theoretically) possible to have a non-null type that is a subtype of both types.

- `Object` to `A<B<C>>`: It is possible for this to succeed. For example, type `A<B<C>>` is a subtype of both.
- `A<?>` to `A<B<C>>`: It is possible for this to succeed. For example, type `A<B<C>>` is a subtype of both.
- `A<B<?>>` to `A<B<C>>`: It is not possible for this to succeed. i.e. there cannot exist a type that is a subtype of both.

To see why for the last one, recall that for parameterized types, `Foo<A>` cannot be a subtype of `Foo<B>` if `A` and `B` are different and neither is a wildcard. So consider `A<B<?>>`. Its parameter, `B<?>` is not a wildcard (it is an actual type; it is not `?`, `? extends something`, or `? super something`).

So the only types that can be a subtype of `A<B<?>>` is itself, and `SubclassOfA<B<?>>`. Same thing applies to `A<B<C>>`: the only types that can be a subtype of `A<B<C>>` is itself, and `SubclassOfA<B<C>>`.

So can you see how it is not possible to have a type that is a subtype of both?

Answer (score 3):

It seems, that your third example violates [first JLS 5.5.1 rule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1):

> If S is a class type:
>
> If T is a class type, then either |S| <: |T|, or |T| <: |S|.
>   Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
>
> Furthermore, if there exists a supertype X of T, and a supertype Y of
>   S, such that both X and Y are provably distinct parameterized types
>   (§4.5), and that the erasures of X and Y are the same, a compile-time
>   error occurs.

Indeed, let `S` be `List<SomeType<?>>>` and `T` be `List<SomeType<X>>`. These `S` and `T` are provably distinct parameterized types, because `<?>` does not equal to `<X>`. At the same time their erasures are the same, just: `List` and `List`.

So, according to specs this leads to compile-time error.

When your firstly cast `m.get(...)` to `Object`, you do not violate mentioned condition: `Object` and `List<SomeType<X>>` do not have same erasures, and furthermore, `|List<SomeType<X>>| <: |Object|`

P.S. as for `List<?>` case, this is also doesn't violate mentioned rule, because `|List<SomeType<X>>| <: |List<?>|`.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is not type-safe.  An example:

```
List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
classes.add(String.class);

// This is invalid!
List<Class<Boolean>> casted = (List<Class<Boolean>>) classes;
// We've somehow assigned a Class<String> to a Class<Boolean>!
Class<Boolean> invalid = casted.get(0);
```

Also, while Java will allow a cast from `Object` to `List<Class<Boolean>>` and from `List<?>` to `List<Class<Boolean>>`, both will produce an unchecked warning.  They are not errors because they could conceivably be type-safe, whereas `List<Class<?>>` to `List<Class<Boolean>>` cannot be type-safe.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
public static <X> List<SomeType<X>> getList(Class<X> clazz)
{
    return (List<SomeType<X>>)m.get(clazz);//will not compile
}
```

It not allowed because, the compiler do not know anything about SomeType.

You have create an method with type parameter `X` and parameter Class, but in result you expect to return a List that store `SomeType` of `X` type. You do not specified how to pass from X to SomeType. The map in get expect `Object`, but return the declared type witch is `SomeType<?>`.

As `?` in this case is more less the same as `X`, you can do something like this.

To fix that you need to say, that that X must be, if you want to use it in return type.

```
public static <X extends SomeType<?>> List<? super X> getList(Class<X> clazz)
{
    return  m.get(clazz); //No error, no warring ;-)
}
```